# basic calculus/analysis question. why does the multivariable chain rule work?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Say $f$ is a function of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

$$\frac{ df}{dt} = \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x} \frac{ dx}{dt} + \frac{ \partial f}{\partial y} \frac{ dy}{dt}$$

why is it so additively symmetric? (The contribution from x and y are additively equal). Basically, why is there a plus sign in there and not some other operator. If the proof is several pages long, I'll settle with a somewhat intuitive explanation.

Equivalently I guess, why is the following true?

$$ df = \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{ \partial f}{\partial y} dy $$

At university, I was just told to assume these were true.

Comment: For the first equation, the two terms are not necessarily equal. They can be different.

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}?$$

Comment: @Mark Fantini Yes I do.

Comment: @Matt S Yes, I know. But that isn't the essence of my question. I'm asking why is there a plus sign in there and not some other operator

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

Comment: Read this [pdf](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ashenk/Section14_4.pdf), p. 319 .

Comment: `We express the change f(x + ∆x, y + ∆y) − f(x, y) in the value of z = f(x, y) from (x, y) to
(x + ∆x, y + ∆y) as the change in the x-direction from (x, y) to (x + ∆x, y) plus the change in the
y-direction from (x + ∆x, y) to (x + ∆x, y + ∆y), as indicated in Figure 1:` But why? Why is it 'plus'?

Comment: $\Delta x$ is just the increment of $x$.  Whether it's added or subtracted doesn't really matter.  You're just moving a little bit away from $x$ -- whether that bit is in the positive or negative direction doesn't matter for the proof so they chose positive (or more likely they just allowed $\Delta x$ to be positive or negative and then it really doesn't matter whether it's $x+\Delta x$ or $x-\Delta x$ -- they are equivalent).  Notice also that in the single-variable case, this is really just $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$, which is just the increment of the function.

Answer (score 0):

For smooth functions, we have primary realization is that whatever behavior the function has globally if you look "close enough" then the function will appear linear. For linear functions $y=mx+b$ we know exactly how to calculate $\Delta y$ from $\Delta x$ and $m$, $\Delta y= m\Delta x$. However, this linearization of the function is only valid only in some infinitesimal neighborhood $dy=mdx$.